# Modifying SubBytes Operation In AES

Tags: encryption, aes, keys

Let us assume the SubBytes operation changed to just shift right operation.
for example - f(00011101) = 10001110

How we perform a Known/ Chosen Plaintext Attack and find the key?
How much time does it take to find it?

Comment: This sounds like a homework question. What have you tried and where are you getting stuck?

Comment: @AmanGrewal Yes, I  thought maybe I can use the birthday attack since in this scenario we "mix" the rows in the AES state (matrice) so each row has fewer permutations? that was my first guess.

Comment: It might be a bit more instructive if you consider either differential or linear cryptanalysis (whichever you're more comfortable with); how does a differential (or a linear characteristic) go through the modified cipher?  What probability does that have?